# API Routes not working properly on Next13.4

Tags: typescript, api, post, next.js, prisma

Stack: Next13.4,Typescript,prisma,postgre(railways app).

So i have created a simple form on which i receive some string data. I am submitting the form and i send a POST request to my api route so i can save it in my DB.

I cannot seem to have any mistakes in my code. I believe that the changes which happened on the 13.4 update of next.js create this problem...?

All i get is: **SubmitForm.tsx:26 POST http://localhost:3000/api/projects net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Anyone faced simmilar problems with next13.4.1? Is there any mistake i miss?

Thanks

**Form (submit code):**

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/projects", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        logo: formData.logo,
        title: formData.title,
        standard: formData.standard,
        twitter: formData.twitter,
        discord: formData.discord,
        telegram: formData.telegram,
        userId: session?.user?.email, // We're assuming you are storing user in your component's state
      }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("form successfully submitted");
      // Handle success - maybe show a notification or redirect the user
    } else {
      console.log("form error");
      // Handle error - show a notification or handle error
    }
  };
```

**Api Route (app/api/projects/route.ts)**

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response("yo");
}

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const { logo, title, standard, twitter, discord, telegram, userId } =
      await request.json();

    // In a production setting you'd want to validate the incoming data here

    const result = await prisma.project.create({
      data: {
        logo: logo,
        title: title,
        standard: standard,
        twitter: twitter,
        discord: discord,
        telegram: telegram,
        userId: userId,
      },
    });
    return NextResponse.json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    NextResponse.json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}
```